# Pass parameter from sheet in Powerquery headers

Tags: excel, rest, powerquery, get-transform

I am querying a REST API in Get & Transform (FKA PowerQuery) in Excel 2016, and I want to parse the API key from a sheet in Excel with parameters.

If I hardcode the API key in the query as part of the headers, all works fine, but if I import it from the sheet and try to use the imported value in the query, I get an authentication failure.

This does work:

```
let
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://app.url.io/api/", [Headers=[Authorization="Basic APIKEY"]]))
in
        Source
```

This also works:

```
let
    API_key = "APIKEY",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("app.url.io/api/", [Headers=[Authorization="Basic "&API_key]]))
in
    Source
```

And this does not work:

```
let
    //API key from parameter table
    API = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="API_key"]}[Content],
    API_key = API{0}[Column1],
    //
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://app.url.io/api/", [Headers=[Authorization="Basic "&API_key]]))
in
    Source
```

Any ideas on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if the following is of any use re: handling authentication using the APIToken query parameter   https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/03/26/working-with-web-services-in-power-query/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, the APIToken method does not seem to work with this API. The key needs to be parsed via the headers.

Comment: What do you see in the final query? What value is API{0}[Column1]? Also, why do you want the API key in the worksheet instead of adding it through the credentials dialog? If you share the workbook, or if the workbook is leaked, then the API key is exposed.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, you are right. My original idea was to have a parameter sheet where it would be easy to parse the API key, but that results in safety issues.  After a bit of digging around, I was able to authenticate via the credentials dialog, so that the API key is not visible anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I found a better solution: I am now using the credentials dialog with Basic authentication, with the API key as username and a blank password. This is safer since the API key is not stored on a sheet anymore nor is it stored in the query.

Thanks!